# How does the back pointer move when using recursion to check a palindrome?

Tags: python, linked-list, palindrome

I have found a recursive solution to check whether a linked list is a palindrome:

```
def isPalindrome(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:

    self.front_pointer = head

    def recursively_check(head):
        if head:
            if not recursively_check(head.next):
                return False
            if self.front_pointer.val != head.val:
                return False
            self.front_pointer = self.front_pointer.next
        return True

    return recursively_check(head)
```

After the `'if head'` statement:

Why are we returning False for the first if statement, when "recursively_check(head.next)" points to None? This would be okay, no? Because it simply means we've reached the end of the linked list, or am I reading this wrongly?

For the second if statement, this kind of makes sense- in my mind it is checking the first node `front_pointer` and the last node `head` are the same?

Then we are simply moving the front_pointer, which initially points to the head of the linked list to the next node to check? But while I understand this, from the back end, how are we moving from the last node to the second last node?

Finally, why do we return the recursive call `recursively_check()`? I don't see when we will reach this code- as we would have returned True or False by the time we reach here, no?

Comment: Have you tested this code, or are you only assuming that it works?

Comment: I have tested it and it works now- the only thing missing was the argument 'head' in the last 'recursive check.

Comment: I suggest you debug it: check the values of `head` and `self.front_pointer` in each call to `recursively_check`. The trick is a bit subtle. Consider what the effect is of having `head` be a function parameter and `front_pointer` be an attribute of the containing object. And try and restrict yourself to one specific question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After the `if head` statement: Why are we returning `False` for the first if statement, when `recursively_check(head.next)` points to `None`? This would be okay, no? Because it simply means we've reached the end of the linked list, or am I reading this wrongly?

`recursively_check(head.next)` does not "point to `None`". It is a boolean: either it is `True`, either it is `False`. Interpret a `True` as "so far it looks like a palindrome" and interpret a `False` as "this definitely is not a palindrome".

This particular `return False` is intended to get out of recursion with a failure that was detected *deeper* in the recursion call tree. Here we just pass on that message to the caller, who will do the same. It is not related to having reached the end of the list. It is triggered by a difference found deeper in the recursion tree.

> For the second if statement, this kind of makes sense- in my mind it is checking the first node front_pointer and the last node head are the same?

Yes, the first time it gets executed, it is like that.

> Then we are simply moving the `front_pointer`, which initially points to the head of the linked list to the next node to check?

Yes

> But while I understand this, from the back end, how are we moving from the last node to the second last node?

This is taken care of by recursion. Each recursive call gets to get its own `head` variable. And as we initialise it with `head.next`, the *deeper* recursive calls will have their `head` initialised *further* in the list.

That means that when we *backtrack* out of a level of recursion, we get into an execution context that has its `head` variable set to a *previous* node than the one that the deeper call was using (as we gave it `head.next`). So by merely returning out of the current execution context, we fall back to a previous value of `head`, which corresponds to taking a step back in the list. But do realise that we have as many `head` variables here as there are nodes in the list. They all get stacked on top of each other in the recursion call stack. By unwinding the call stack we get to work with the previous `head` variable.

> Finally, why do we return the recursive call `recursively_check()`? I don't see when we will reach this code- as we would have returned True or False by the time we reach here, no?

We  reach this statement immediately. The function above it, is not yet executed when we arrive there. It is this statement that will start the recursion, and we need to get information from that call, and that information is what we want to return.

This is the only `return` statement for `isPalindrome`. The other `return` statements serve `recursively_check` only. They don't execute a return for `isPalindrome`.

Every time we exit a nested execution of `recursively_check` we have tested one more pair of nodes. If ever we find a difference in value, we start returning `False`. Like explained above, this `False` will from then on be the return value for all unfinished calls of `recursively_check`, including the one that is made directly in `isPalindrome`.

On the other hand, as long as the comparisons are equal, a `True` will be returned by each nested `recursively_check` call. If it turns out the comparisons were *always* equal, then also `isPalindrome`'s call to `recursively_check` will get a `True` back.